# Refresh page does not apply changes in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why sometimes refresh of page (F5) does not apply changes on view, even if I have JS and HTML code? I have to clear browsing and tmp files and refresh again. I know that angular saves a lot of cache data but it is very problematic when I want to see changes and there is no update on screen. Than I do not know if it is my mistake in code or there is a problem with Angular. How to fix it?

Comment: clear cache of your browser

Comment: Use cache clear extension in your browser or CTRL+SHIFT+R to clear cache and reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At development stage you can deactivate the browser cache -

In Chrome Dev Tools go to settings and click "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" or you can go to network tab and check option "Disable Cache"

In Firefox and IE also we have similar options where we can disable cache while dev tools are open.

For me this is the easiest options without making any code changes.